# RPi3 Noobs with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, noobs

I'm fairly familiar with debian linux, but having a little problem with the getting NOOBS running. I installed OSMC direct dd to the flash without problems without NOOBS. I installed UbuntuMATE without NOOBS and was successful. I want to install a clean Raspbian Jessie. I ran the windows SDFormatter4 to format a 64GB U1 sd card. I extracted all the files in NOOBS 1.9.2. I took all those contents and copied them onto the SD card, and then booted up a RPi3 that I know works with OSMC, but it doesn't do anything, just one led.

Any ideas what I should do? I think I ran through all the instructions provided in the readme file.

Comment: Since you are familiar with burning an image to the SD card why not bypass noobs and burn the Raspbian image directly to your card?

Comment: Steve's right.  Despite the implication that it's easier,  as far as I can tell NOOBs just adds a layer of complication, and I think we get more people here with screwed up NOOBs installs than screwed up plain Raspbian installs -- and there are probably a lot more plain Raspbian users too.

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it won't boot is SD FORMATTER formats 64GB SD cards to EXFAT. Raspberry only read FAT32 SD cards. You need to use a different tool to format then copy the files over.

Answer (score 0):

See these two posts which answer your problem and give links to the microSD card formatter and then a FAT32 formatter tool being used successfully.  It's a two step formatting process.  These links explain why.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=83372&p=651745#p677748

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=160815&p=1041950#p1041950

Comment: Could you please include the details in your answer.

Comment: I think this falls under our [new policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538).  While you have at least said how the links are relevant, the post still doesn't contain information that stands an a direct answer to the question.  If this post is not edited to include such details, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.